# UITableView Crash on scroll , add or delete cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I've just changed my population method to use a plist and it's caused a crash upon attempting to add or delete a cell. Scrolling the table also causes a crash. I am not using IB and this is all created programmatically. Searching questions results in no answers or IB related solutions. What I have for code is

```
//****************** Set Table Data



NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"stuff" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
devices = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"Devices"]];


//****************** Customize Number of Rows in Table


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    int count = [devices count];
    if(self.editing) count++;
    return count;
}


//****************** Customize the Cells


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %i",indexPath.section]];

    if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %i",indexPath.section]] autorelease];

}

    switch(indexPath.section){
    case 0:{ cell.textLabel.text = [devices objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];} break;
    default: break;
}


    return cell;

}
```

This is what I have deemed relevant code since everything was fine until I populated from a plist.

More code has been requested

```
 //***************** Allow Editing of Cells

  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 [devices removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [myTable reloadData];

}



//****************** Add New Cell If ok button is pressed

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

UITextField * newDevice = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"newDevice - %@",newDevice.text);

if (alertView.tag == 1 && buttonIndex == 1){
[devices addObject: newDevice.text];
[myTable reloadData];
```

**UPDATE**

Commenting out my data loading solves the crash leading me to believe I've incorrectly invoked the way to load data. Of course I'll look into this and appreciate a bigger brain throwing in his two cents in the mean time.

Comment: add the crash report, so it will be helpful to all.

Comment: What is `self.editing`?

Comment: show your add or delete a cell code

Comment: Since I'm not using IB I have no crash report :) Nor do I have access to a Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. It seems my array was being auto released instantly and a manual retain then release fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

Change `switch` to

```
 switch(indexPath.section){
   case 0:{ 
       if ([devices count] > indexPath.row) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [devices objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
       }
   } break;
   default: break;
 }
```

Comment: Still a crash. This is also where I suspect my problem to be if it's not within my 'numberOfRowsInSection' method.